# Should be Qt Widget's constructor used to link to a parent function?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

With the multiple instances of the same `QListWidget` and all instances to be connected to the same function it seems like I could save a few lines of code by moving:

```
self.clicked.connect(self.parent().itemClicked)
```

to its constructor.

While it works I wonder if a such practice would be considered bad? If it is then please explain why:

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.clicked.connect(self.parent().itemClicked)

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout) 

        view=ListWidget(self) 
        view.addItems(['One','Two','Three']) 

        layout.addWidget(view)

    def itemClicked(self, index):
        print 'itemClicked', index

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is bad because it **creates additional coupling** between `ListWidget` class and other class with `itemClicked` slot. Child class should not know what its parent does. What if `ListWidget` is a child of another widget, that has no `itemClicked` slot?

I would suggest having a factory function that will create a ListWidget and set its connection(s). I would write it as (C++):

```
static ListWidget *createListWidget(MainWindow *parent)
{
    ListWidget *lw = new ListWidget(parent);
    connect(lw, SIGNAL(clicked(int)), parent, SLOT(itemClicked(int)));
    return lw;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow()
    {
        [..]
        ListWidget *lw = createListWidget(this);
        lw->addItems(...);
        layout->addWidget(lw);
        [..]
    }
};
```